# what is wrong with this part of c++ code?

Tags: c++

```
int f =0;
    std::cout << " do you want to use 1. component y or n " << std::endl;
    std::cin >>f;
    if(f == 'y' || f =='n'){
        if (f =='y'){
            this->decisionvector[0] = 1;
        }else 
            this->decisionvector[0] = 0;

    }

    std::cout << " do you want to use 2. component y or n " << std::endl;
    std::cin >>f;
    if(f == 'y' || f=='n'){
        if (f =='y'){
            this->decisionvector[1] = 2;
        }else 
            this->decisionvector[1] = 0;
        f= 0;
    }
    std::cin.clear(); 
    std::cout << " do you want to use 3. component y or n " << std::endl;
    std::cin >>f;
    if(f == 'y' || f =='n'){
        if (f =='y'){
            this->decisionvector[2] = 4;
        }else 
            this->decisionvector[2] = 0;
        f= 0;
    }
    std::cin.clear(); 
    std::cout << " do you want to use 4. component y or n " << std::endl;
    std::cin >>f;
    if(f == 'y' || f =='n'){
        if (f =='y'){
            this->decisionvector[3] = 8;
        }else 
            this->decisionvector[3] = 0;
        f= 0;
    }
```

why I can set f only in the first if statement the program doesn't stop at the others ?

Comment: In the second block you're reading into `k` but comparing `f`. That's clearly wrong.

Comment: I edited the code it still the same problem

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger, and see what's going on.

Comment: after the first if statement f is 0  and in cin >> f doesn't wait for an input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change `int f` to `char f`

Comment: I'm only guessing, but the first thing it comes to my mind is about physical dimensions of char and int (8 bit, 16 for unicode and 4 bytes for int). Yes, you can check a char with a number, like 'c' == 35, but I don't think it's safe and correct to do with a int variable.

Comment: @Engine `std::cin::operator>>(int&)` will parse the character sequence into an integer value. `std::operator>>(istream& is, char& c)` will extract the character and store its value *as is*.

Answer (score 2):

```
int f =0;
std::cin >>f;
```

[`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) reads and *interprets* the sequence of character.

If `f` is an `int`, it will use the `int` overload of the extraction operator `operator>>`. This operator will try to format the input as an integer.

If the user pass the character `'y'`, the operator will fail to interpret it as a integer and will store `0` in `f`. You can check the error state of the stream with `cin.fail()`.

if you want to read a character, you have to use a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

In the second block you're reading k but using y...

```
std::cin >>k;
if(k == 'y' || k=='n'){
    if (f =='y'){
        this->decisionvector[1] = 2;
    }else 
        this->decisionvector[1] = 0;
    f= 0;
}
```